# Twilio - define parameters with inbound SMS webhook

Tags: twilio

I was building a project which using Twilio to remind users about their tasks by SMS, and enable them to reply with digits like (1 to mark as done, 2 to postponed).

But I got lost when I trying to pass Task ID to Twilio inbound SMS webhook, so I can complete or postponed task by its ID, I spent 2 days in vain between Twilio Docs and google trying but couldn't find any way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm having a similar problem and can't seem to find a solution...

Comment: No, I didn't. Instead I stored a reminder details in database when it's time to be sent, and find those details by matching returning phone number vs the one in database.